# Stack of matrices with unequal sizes

Tags: matrices

I have to write a list of two matrix equations. They are almost identical, but the elements in one matrix are slightly larger than the other one, which makes it look badly.

```
\begin{align}
  \begin{pmatrix}
    -\id & \id \\
     \id & -\id \\
  \end{pmatrix}  u = 0 \\
  \begin{pmatrix}
    \id &   \id \\
     \id &  \id
  \end{pmatrix}  v = 0 
\end{align}
```

Is there a simple and elegant way to make the two matrices match size? I've found [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/288902/equal-spacing-in-two-matrices-with-matrix-entries-of-differing-length), but it is a much complex case than mine. Is there something simpler?

Comment: Seems very related to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/300492/make-column-widths-of-multiple-matrix-columns-equal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose two versions, the second one is what I'd prefer.

The `calc` packages is necessary only for the first solution. As a general rule, never use `align` without alignment points.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,calc}
\newcommand{\id}{\mathrm{id}}
\newcommand{\cid}{\makebox[\widthof{$-\id$}]{$\id$}}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\begin{pmatrix}
  -\id & \id \\
   \id & -\id \\
\end{pmatrix}  u &= 0 \\
\begin{pmatrix}
  \cid &  \cid \\
  \cid &  \cid
\end{pmatrix}  v &= 0 
\end{align}
A different version
\begin{gather}
\begin{pmatrix}
  -\id & \id \\
   \id & -\id \\
\end{pmatrix}  u = 0 \\
\begin{pmatrix}
  \id &  \id \\
  \id &  \id
\end{pmatrix}  v = 0 
\end{gather}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here are two solutions, far from perfect. I use the variants of the matrix environments defined by `mathtools`, which allow to specify the alignment in a matrix and I modify the value of `\arraycolsep` when needed.

I  also define  a `\nid` math operator, which corrects the spacing between `–` and `id` in `-\id`, which is bad.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{textcomp} \usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\DeclareMathOperator{\id}{{id}}
\newcommand*\nid{\ensuremath{-{\id}}}%
\newcommand*\varnid{\ensuremath{\mskip-5mu-{\id}}}
\newcommand*\varid{\ensuremath{\mskip-5mu\phantom{-}{\id}}}%

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
  \begin{pmatrix*}[r]
  \varnid & \id \\
  \id & \nid \\
  \end{pmatrix*} u = 0 \\
  \setlength\arraycolsep{0.9em}
  \begin{pmatrix*}[r]
  \varid & \id \\
  \id & \id
  \end{pmatrix*} v = 0 \\
  \setlength\arraycolsep{1.1em}
  \begin{pmatrix*}[r]
  \id & \id \\
  \id & \id
  \end{pmatrix*} v = 0
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The package `nicematrix` has tools designed to address that kind of problem. In particular, there is an environment `{NiceMatrixBlock}` with a key `auto-columns-width` to impose the same width for all the columns of the matrices in a  given scope. However, you need several compilations.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\DeclareMathOperator{\id}{{id}}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceMatrixBlock}[auto-columns-width]
\NiceMatrixOptions{right-margin=2pt}

\begin{align}
  \begin{pNiceMatrix}[r]
  -\id & \id \\
  \id & -\id \\
  \end{pNiceMatrix} u = 0 \\
  \begin{pNiceMatrix}[r]
  \id & \id \\
  \id & \id
  \end{pNiceMatrix} v = 0 \\
  \begin{pNiceMatrix}[r]
  \id & \id \\
  \id & \id
  \end{pNiceMatrix} v = 0
\end{align}

\end{NiceMatrixBlock}


\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]